# Jenkins Master and Slave behaving differently

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Looking for some advice on our Jenkins slave set up. Up until now we've just had a master box. All of the jobs are pipelines that are run from groovy Jenkinsfile stored in svn. These scripts variously refer to other scripts that are in the same directory as the Jenkinsfile and come as part of the checkout. We've decided to add a slave to our setup but are finding that Jenkins behaves differently when jobs are run on the slave.

When a job is run on the master the scripts are checked out into a location like:

```
<JenkinsHome>/<Workspaces>/<JobName>@Script/
```

However, when run on the slave, initially there is no checkout so there are no scripts available. We've forced the checkout in the Jenkinsfile by adding a

```
checkout scm
```

at the start of the script but this will checkout the scripts to a location like:

```
<JenkinsHome>/<Workspaces>/<JobName>/
```

*Note the lack of @Script*

We can work around this by having the script look in a number of places for the files it needs but I was wondering if anyone else had come accross a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why are you using absolute paths?

Comment: We're not. We pick up the path programmatically. But on the Master you end up with a structure like:

<JenkinsHome>/<Workspaces>/<JobName>/ -- Main Workspace
<JenkinsHome>/<Workspaces>/<JobName>@Script/ -- Where the scripts from the checkout are.

Whereas on the slave you get:

<JenkinsHome>/<Workspaces>/<JobName>/ -- Main Workspace and where the scripts from the checkout are.

Answer (score 0):

Close this off. Down to our fundamental misunderstanding of how the master and slave work with each other.

Comment: I think you can delete it?